# Edit off-topic question with valuable answer?

Tags: support, scope, editing, specific-question, policy

At first sight, it appears that our [policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/3073) on changing question meanings would discourage editing [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47635/3073) question, because it already has a valuable answer. But is that still true when the question is off-topic, thus displaying a banner that asks readers to "please edit the question"?

Comment: If not, we should have an alternative version off the off-topic banner, that omits the edit request – to be used when there is already a valuable answer.

Comment: The same was true of [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46048/5323) and [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46048/5323) (especially first edit). See [my comment there](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46048/i-accidentally-broke-my-fast-on-yom-kippur-now-what/46049#comment124130_46049).

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, no, it doesn't still hold true in such a case. A closed question is one that should have no answers. (In an ideal world, it would be closed before it got answered.) It should indeed be edited to be brought on-topic (or, if it's not editable to be brought on-topic, should be deleted or have an historical lock put on it), and any no-longer-on-point answers can (and should) then be edited to reflect the change to the question, or deleted. (Ideally, edit the question so it's on-topic and so any good answers remain answers to the new question. But that won't always be possible.)