# What to do if you answered a question which was then edited further to another topic

Tags: discussion, support

If you answered a question, and a posteriori, your answer is not relevant to the question because the question was edited to a different question?

Is there a possibility for someone who asks a question to modify it to another topic, e.g. a question about lulav changed to a question about matsa?

I ask this because I noticed that [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109667/9215) I tried to answer yesterday is today another question.

Is there a policy to prohibit some edits of the question that can lead to a lack of coherence with answers already existing. It seems that if I wrote a question and people answered, I can further  change the question without problem.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/170

Comment: @msh duplicate?

Comment: @dou that asks whether one can edit the question. This asks what to do if someone did so.

Comment: Right the question is about the policy  for the asker. Can he change at all the question. It seems to me that he can. this may generate problems of coherence in the site.

Comment: @msh210 What about [this one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5025/changed-questions-answer-etiquette) then?

Comment: kouty, is there anything that the two linked-to questions don't, together, resolve for you? If so, please edit this one to specify what it is.

Comment: Yes it's duplicate. Anyways, the answer there is a little silky. @msh210

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "silky".

Comment: A way to answer and not answering together